# DocuSignAPI - Retrieving Details of Envelope Sender

Tags: api, docusignapi

I'm trying to find a way to get the email address of an envelope sender through the REST API.  So far, no luck.

It's not in the envelope response, or in the recipients.

Any ideas of how I can find the envelope sender?

Kind Regards,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little bit of a round-about way of doing this, but you can can use the envelope audit events call to get the UserId and then use that to retrieve the user's profile using https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/**accountID/users/**userIDhere**

Another option that I utilize is to capture the information when the user sends the envelope and attach it as a custom field. This allows you to make the custom fields call to retrieve the information rather than digging through audit events and making additional calls.

Comment: I think that adding a custom tag will make them a signer correct?  We have some documents that we don't need the sender to prefill, we just need the recipient to sign, so it would add an extra step for the sender.  However, we'll give the audit events a go!  Cheers!

Comment: Custom Fields are different from custom tags. They are a meta-data field that can be added to an envelope and are invisible to the recipient. In xml it would look something like this.

Comment: Sorry hit 5 min edit time mark.

`<customFields >
    <textCustomFields>      
        <textCustomField>
            <fieldId>autogenerated</fieldId>
            <name>Envelope Type</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <show>true</show>
            <value>Disclosures</value>
        </textCustomField>
</customFields>`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a way to get the envelope sender email, however, with the Envelope Audit Events you are able to get the UserName of the sender.

[Documentation on call](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Audit%20Events.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____48)

Answer (score 1):

Payloads from the [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect) service contain ACHolder and ACHolderEmail nodes which specify the name and email address of the sender, respectively. This may be another option for you.

Comment: Haha Mark is that you?? Jim here (your very lucky replacement) ;) Good to see you on SE!

Comment: Also, connect is an option when we move to PROD, however in initial dev we can't get an open port to run a listener, so have to do this all through Rest API polling.